# conditional statement with logical operators for thingspeak data

Tags: matlab, conditional-statements, logical-operators

I am working on a thingspeak code on matlab analysis for my weather station which checks last 24 readings and then gives alert on the basis of given conditions, and I gave this condition but I guess I am messing up with something hence getting wrong results. I want the answer to be overall logical 1 or 0. I get 1's for even the values that should not give me one and the answer for both variables is a 24*1 logical array. But even then the tweets are not being generated as well. Here's my code;

```
    t =thingSpeakRead(293182,'Fields',1,'NumPoints',24,'OutputFormat','matrix');
h =thingSpeakRead(293182,'Fields',2,'NumPoints',24,'OutputFormat','matrix');

DangerAlert = ((t>42.5)&(t<43.5)&(h>17)&(h<21))|(((t>40.5)&(t<43.5))&((h>21)&(h<27)))|((t>39.5)&(t<43.5)&(h>27)&(h<31)) |   ((t>38.5)&(t<43.5)&(h>31)&(h<37))| ((t>37.5)&(t<42.5)&(h>37)&(h<41))|   ((t>36.5)&(t<40.5)&(h>41)&(h<47))|   ((t>35.5)&(t<39.5)&(h>47)&(h<51))|   ((t>34.5)&(t<38.5)&(h>51)&(h<57))|  ((t>33.5)&(t<38.5)&(h>57)&(h<68))|   ((t>33.5)&(t<37.5)&(h>63)&(h<68)) |   ((t>32.5)&(t<38.5)&(h>68)&(h<73)) | ((t>31.5)&(t<35.5)&(h>73)&(h<83))|   ((t>30.5)&(t<33.5)&(h>83)&(h<88)) |   ((t>29.5)&(t<33.5)&(h>83)&(h<93))|   ((t>29.5)&(t<32.5)&(h>93)&(h<100))

HeatStrokeAlert=((t>42.5)&(t<43.5)&(h>37)&(h<41)) |  ((t>40.5)&(t<2.5)&(h>41)&(h<47)) | ((t>39.5)&(t<41.5)&(h>47)|(h<51))|  ((t>38.5)&(t<40.5)&(h>51)&(h<57))|  ((t>38.5)&(t<39.5)&(h>57)&(h<63))| ((t>37.5)&(t<38.5)&(h>63)&(h<68))|  ((t>36.5)&(t<38.5)&(h>68)&(h<78))| ((t>35.5)&(t<37.5)&(h>73)&(h<83)) |  ((t>34.5)&(t<36.5)&(h>83)&(h<88)) |  ((t>33.5)&(t<36.5)&(h>88)&(h<93)) |  ((t>33.5)&(t<35.5)&(h>93)&(h<97)) |  ((t>32.5)&(t<34.5)&(h>97))    

if DangerAlert
webwrite('http://api.thingspeak.com/apps/thingtweet/1/statuses/update','api_key', 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX', 'status', 'Alert!Dangerously High temperature tomorrow!')
end
if HeatStrokeAlert
webwrite('http://api.thingspeak.com/apps/thingtweet/1/statuses/update','api_key', 'XXXXXXXXX', 'status', 'Alert!Heat Stroke alert tomorrow!')
end
```

I know the blunder is minor.But this needs to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your range values for t go from 29.5 to 43.5, and for h go from 17 to 100. So any value you put in between those numbers will give you a 1, because you are using the OR statements ||. So if ANY one of those is true, it will come back true (=1).

Also, for the website, make sure you follow these directions:
https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/webwrite.html

Make sure you have a ThinkSpeak account, and try changing your URL to match their format:
 [thingSpeakURL 'update'];
So add 'update' string and use brackets.

Also, set your if statement expression to one. So:
if DangerAlert = 1